# Using multiple losses and multiple training steps in a TF2 model using subclassing?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, subclassing, generative-adversarial-network

I am implementing a generative adversarial autoencoder in TF2. I have got it working but not optimally and could use some high level advise to improve it.

The model is inspired by the paper “Adversarial Factorization Autoencoder for Look-alike Modeling” https://dmkd.cs.vt.edu/papers/CIKM19.pdf

The model consists of three parts: an encoder/generator, a decoder and a discriminator.

[image]

I have implemented these three parts as custom classes, each subclassing from tf.keras.Model (which is primary source of my issues). I have three different loss functions (autoencoder loss, generator loss, discriminator loss) and two custom training step functions.

The first training function trains first the autoencoder (using the autoencoder loss function) and then the generator (using the generator loss function). The generator is just the encoder part of the autoencoder but having the double purpose of also fooling the discriminator).

The second training function trains the discriminator using the discriminator loss function.

This approach works ok but subclassing all three parts from tf.keras.Model has limitations. I can’t utilize keras compile and fit functionalities. Callbacks are a nightmare and I really do need early stopping, keep best model, tensorboard integration and so on. It appears the best approach is to subclass each part from tf.keras.layers.Layer and then combine them in a single custom model. But I am not sure if it is at all possible to wire up multiple loss functions and multiple training steps to different layer blocks of a custom model?

Any hints and insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a custom training loop?

Comment: A custom training loop is evidently necessary. Question is where it should be put. Should it be put inside a train_step function of a model encompassing all three components so that I can use use fit/compile and thus get callbacks or whether I have to do it outside the models and loose having all the inbuilt stuff like callbacks.